# Get error messages from server

Tags: services, xinetd

I want to start a service via xinetd but it does not work.
That means immediately after starting the service it is stopped again:

```
Sep 23 19:16:39 sektor xinetd[556]: START: service pid=559 from=xx.xx.xx.xx
Sep 23 19:16:39 sektor xinetd[556]: EXIT: service status=1 pid=559 duration=0(sec)
```

Is there any way to get error messages from the service to track down the problem?

I found [something for x11vnc](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=2377920&postcount=19) that says to use `-o /path/to/separate/logfile`, but I would like to know if this works with every (x)inetd-able service or if it even is a flag of xinetd itself.

Comment: `-o` is an argument to the `x11vnc` command specifically.

Comment: @grawity so it is up to the services to provide logging whilst running under (x)inetd?

Comment: It is *always* up to the services - most use syslog, some log to files, others nowhere - not dependent on xinetd.

Comment: @grawity: Ok maybe logging was the wrong word. When I start for example x11vnc on commandline it gives me a lot of output on stdout. Of course this is not possible under xinetd, because the stdout is reserved for the communication. So a service that runs under xinetd should always provide some possibility to get the output that "normally" would be on stdout?

Comment: In such cases, a properly written service is supposed to use Syslog (or its own log file, if necessary). Also, by the way, most programs use *stderr* for such messages, and a smarter version of inetd (such as systemd) could redirect stderr to a log while keeping stdin/out with the socket.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look into `/var/log/messages` or into the service specific logfile (found in `/var/log` too, if it exist).

Which service do you try to start?

Comment: It is x11vnc and the lines I posted were the only ones that I found in the log (I redirected xinetd's output to /var/log/xinetd.log to not bloat my messages file). But the messages file also does not say anything.

Comment: Try starting xinetd with the `-d` option. The man page says: "Enables debug mode. This produces a lot of debugging output, and it makes it possible to use a debugger on xinetd.". This should give you a hint.